# Volume of a Solid of Rotation Without Shells

Tags: calculus, integration, solid-of-revolution

My math teacher told me to find the volume of the solid formed when one rotates the region bounded by $x^3 +x+1, x = a, \text{and } x=b \text{ around }y=c.$ With shells this is relatively simple, but he told me to do it without them, using the washer method.  How might I do this?